# ASP.NET MVC Erro ao identificar arquivo de estilo

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Publiquei um site que esta em MVC4 neste endereço.
http://acensao-com-br.umbler.net/Login

Ao tentar acessar recebo esta mensagem de erro:

> "Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath"

Linha onde ocorre o erro:

```
@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
```

Qual é a razão deste erro?

O site funciona normalmente em ambiente local.

Esta section esta declarada em apenas algumas paginas que podem ter outros arquivos de estilos opcionais.

```
@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/chosen")
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/datetimepicker")
}
```

Por isso ela está marcada no arquivo _Layout.cshtml como "required: false"

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
```

BuddleConfig

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            //JS

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mask").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.mask.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/maskMoney").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/chosen").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js",
                        "~/Scripts/chosen.proto.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datetimepicker").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/datepicker-pt-BR.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/digitalClock").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/digitalClock.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/msgBox").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/messagebox.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"));

            //ESTILOS CSS

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/chosen").Include(
                      "~/Content/chosen.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/datetimepicker").Include(
                      "~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/digitalClock").Include(
                      "~/Content/clock.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/msgBox").Include(
                      "~/Content/messagebox.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/jqueryui").Include(
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.min.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css"));

        }
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@using ControleHoras.APRESENTACAO.Models
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/chosen")
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/datetimepicker")
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/digitalClock")

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logo"])" alt="" style="border: none; width: 150px; height: 50px;" />
                </a>

            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                @if (Session["usuario"] != null)
                {
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            @{
                                if (Session["usuario"] != null)
                                {
                                    var usuario = (UsuarioViewModel)Session["usuario"];
                                    if (usuario.ClienteID.HasValue && usuario.ClienteID.Value > 0)
                                    {
                                        @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Horas Extras", "HorasExtras", "Login")</li>*@
                                    }
                                    if (usuario.ProfissionalID.HasValue && usuario.ProfissionalID.Value > 0)
                                    {
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Lançamentos", "Lancamento", "Login")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Relatórios de Horas", "RelatorioHoras", "Relatorio")</li>
                                    }
                                    if (usuario.Adm)
                                    {
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Clientes<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastro", "Search", "Cliente")</li>
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configurações de Rede", "Index", "ClienteIp")</li>
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Loalização", "Index", "ClienteLocal")</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contratos", "Contrato", "Login")</li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Profissional<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastro", "Search", "Profissional")</li>
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dispositivos Móveis", "Index", "ProfissionalDispositivo")</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Lançamentos", "Lancamento", "Login")</li>
                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Usuários", "Usuario", "Login")</li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Relatórios<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Relatórios de Horas", "RelatorioHoras", "Relatorio")</li>
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Demonstrativo de Horas", "DemonstrativoHoras", "Relatorio")</li>
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Relatório de Faturamento", "RelatorioFaturamento", "Relatorio")</li>
                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acompanhamento Diário de Lançamentos", "AcompanhamentoDiario", "Relatorio")</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            }
</ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Sair", "Logout", "Login")</li>
                    </ul>
                            }
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <footer class="rodape">
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["empresa"] </p>
    </footer>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <!--MessageBox-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/msgBox")
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/msgBox")
    <!--Jquery UI-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/jqueryui")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Precisa de mais detalhes pra te ajudar. Como você está fazendo o deploy? Copiando e colando os arquivos? Outra coisa, tem como postar o arquivo `BundleConfig`?

Comment: Como você disse que o site funciona em ambiente local, verifique se o section está apontando para algum lugar na sua máquina e não no caminho de ambiente. 
O erro mostra este caminho "E:\Domains\acensao.com.br\public\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" Verifique se o site consegue chegar até ele.

Comment: @jbueno estou gerando os arquivos de deploy através do PUBLISH do Visual Studio

Comment: @GabrielHeguedusch não estou utilizando caminho físico na aplicação. Todos os arquivos de estilos e scripts estão referenciados no buddleconfig desta maneira: bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

Comment: @OtavioCamargo Esse é o bundle de verdade ou só exemplo?

Comment: @jbueno é esse que esta em meu codigo. E a pasta content esta publicada no site.

Comment: va no shared_layout.cshtml e declare essa linha:
@section Styles
{
//links do seus css ou @Styles.Render(...)
}

Comment: Poste o seu arquivo `_Layout.cshtml` e o arquivo da página de login.

Comment: Por favor, poste seu BundleConfig também

Comment: Acabei de mutar todos os arquivos de estilo para _Layout.html, e removi o RenderSection("Styles"), para ver se era esse o problema. Mas continua dando erro. Parece que ele não esta reconhecendo alguns arquivos. Agora deu erro na linha @Styles.Render("~/styles/digitalClock")

Comment: Acabo de fazer mais um teste. Comentei todas as referencias de scripts e css. Agora recebo a mesma mensagem de erro na chamada de ViewBag.Title. Alguma configuração do projeto deve estar errada, pois agora não esta mais funcionado nem local

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu problema seja relacionado ao @Url.Content que não pode ser nulo.

No trecho que pega o logo tem essa chamada, tente remover esse trecho para validar se esse é o problema.

Página _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logo"])" alt="" style="border: none; width: 150px; height: 50px;" />
                </a>
```